# Cannot create new plotting window (device?) with par(new=T)

Tags: r, plot

I want to create a new window for each additional plot in R. I tried

```
plot(rnorm(20), new=TRUE)
```

and also

```
par(new=T)
plot(rnorm(20), new=TRUE)
```

Neither gives me a new window. Do I really need to create a new device?

Comment: yes, open a new device with dev.new(); it's probably what you're after

Comment: What R interface are you using?  AFAIK, RStudio doesn't (yet) allow multiple plot windows.

Comment: In RStudio, you have to open a new windows device by `x11()`, `windows()` or `quartz()`, depending on your OS; `dev.new()` will not work.

Comment: If this is the case I'd personally consider this a bug in Rstudio rather than something to do with R per se

Answer (score 12):

The `plot.new()` function is used to start a new plot on the current device and will open a default device if there is not a device currently open.  If you want a new device (so that you have the old plot in one window and the new plot in another window) then use `dev.new()` or other device functions.

Answer (score 2):

`par(new = T)` is used for plotting over an existing plot.  You will need to create a new device for each plot, closed with `dev.off()`.  If you want multiple plots in the same window, try using `par(mfrow=c(2,2)` for 2 rows of 2 plots.