# Error in plot.new()

Tags: r, plot, rstudio, rstudio-server

I'm using R Studio when doing some GIS plots. Unfortunately I keep getting this same error but only on certain maps.

> Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

I know its an issue with the plotting window size but I'm wondering if there is a way to edit the default settings without having to manually change the window size every time?

Comment: The plot box in Rstudio is too small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter R to plot to a different device, which can let you pop out the plot in a separate window.

A Windows solution:

```
plot_data <- sample(1:100,100)
windows(width=500,height=500)
plot(plot_data,type="o")
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9299392/cannot-create-new-plotting-window-device-with-parnew-t).